# How perform Code coverage for my project. I wrote unit test in spec flow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design, code-coverage, specflow

I have written  unit test for my .net core web-api project in specflow(mstest).Im able to run all the tests. Now I want check the code coverage. Some one please guide me to perform code coverage.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Visual Studio Enterprise you can use the built in option to calculate code coverage:

[image: The calculate code coverage option in the Test menu of Visual Studio]

You can also calculate code coverage from the command line.

1. Add the [coverlet.msbuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/coverlet.msbuild) package to your test project.
2. Run `dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"` on your test project

This will output an XML file `coverage.cobertura.xml` that contains the code coverage information.

You can then use the [ReportGenerator .NET tool](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) to create a visualization of your code coverage like this:

```
reportgenerator
-reports:"Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml"
-targetdir:"coveragereport"
-reporttypes:Html
```

For more details on these steps see [Use code coverage for unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage)